How to plot hazard ratio from coxph model with tt() term
This question is related to another that I posted here:
How to visually assess tt() suitability in coxph?
If we have a time-varying HR that arises from a time-dependent coefficient because we have specified a time-transform using tt(), how do we plot that?
Using the example from the survival vignette, if we specified a model incorporating a spline term on karno because of non-proportional hazards:
library(survival)
fit.tt3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno), data = veteran,
                 tt = function(x, t, ...) x * nsk(t, knots = c(5, 20, 50, 150, 300),
                                                  Boundary.knots = FALSE))

Is there a straightforward way (well, any way would be good) to plot the HR for karno as a function of time? It would be good to be able to communicate to other members of a research team, what the time-dependence means by showing them a simple figure?
Thanks
